Minimal example of C++ concurrency bug due to one thread loading the value at thread startup
At 6:44 of the talk "Real-time Confessions in C++", the speaker shows buggy code that essentially boils down to:

Thread A writes to an unsynchronized integer called x
Much later, thread B reads x (in a loop)
Thread B does not see the updated value of x because the optimizing compiler realized that thread B never changed x, and thus the value of x could be loaded once at the start of the thread and never again.

The speaker is trying to prove that synchronization is necessary even on, say, a single core machine, since otherwise the compiler optimizations can render your code buggy.
I am trying to come up with a minimal example of this bug. Here is what I have:
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <unistd.h>

int var;  // unsynchronized, i.e., no std::atomic or anything

void f() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        sleep(1);
        int x = var * var;
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    var = 1;

    std::thread t(f);
  
    sleep(2);
    var = 10;

    t.join();
}

My hope is that inside f(), the compiler will realize that it can load var and compute x once at the beginning of the thread, instead of loading var over and over in the loop, thereby never seeing that the value of var was changed from 1 to 10 on the main thread.
Unfortunately, the program behaves "correctly" as shown:
$ clang++ -O3 test.cpp && ./a.out
1
100
100
100
...

I was hoping for the output to be all 1s.
What am I doing wrong? How do I properly create a minimal example of this concurrency bug?

I suspect sleep is the "issue" in f, compiler can't assume it doesn't have side effects.

The general rule is that multi-threading race bugs are rare and hard to reproduce. This is why they are also hard to debug.

@273K I set var to 1 in the first line of main()

@prapin True, multi-threading bugs are usually hard to reproduce because they rely on the OS scheduling threads just right. But this bug is about a compiler optimization and does not rely on a fringe case of scheduling. So it should be easily reproducible once we can come up with a proper code example.

@Mat If I modify f to remove the sleep call and make the loop run forever, it still starts printing 100s after a while. Which makes me think that sleep is not the issue.

The iostream calls also could have side effects (and synchronization like sleep could). Try writing the result of the multiplication to a global array, and don't call any function in f. Then look at the assembly to see if var is reloaded in the loop or not.

The problem with UB is that anything goes if you have one. Reproducing the problem resulting from UB is not easy. The compiler always assumes that code is UB free; thus it can optimize code in crazy ways. If you do not sync multithreaded access to shared objects, compiler may assume ownership in each function, and create a distinct copy for each thread(as long copy is trivial). Do not make any assumptions in presence of UB; just remove it properly.

I would never have assumed that I'd write something like this, but here's a "fixed" example that, well, "breaks properly". At least on my box.
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <unistd.h>

bool test=false;  // unsynchronized, i.e., no std::atomic or anything
volatile bool quit=false;

void f() {
    std::cout << "thread: " << test << "\n";
    unsigned long long count=0;
    while (!quit) {
        count++;
        if (test) {
            std::cout << "changed\n";
            break;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "loops: " << count << "\n";
    std::cout << "thread: " << test << "\n";
}

int main() {
    std::thread t(f);

    sleep(1);
    test=true;
    std::cout << "main: " << test << "\n";

    sleep(1);
    quit=true;

    t.join();
}

If we run this without optimization, I get this:
stieber@gatekeeper:~ $ g++ Test.cpp; ./a.out
thread: 0
changed
loops: 150478526
thread: 1
main: 1

So, we can properly detect the change mid-thread.
Now, let's try this with optimization:
stieber@gatekeeper:~ $ g++ -O3 Test.cpp; ./a.out
thread: 0
main: 1
loops: 1494121136
thread: 1

As you can see, the "changed" message never appears, because the compiler optimized it away.
In contrast to your code, I avoided all calls to functions that the compiler can't see. If you call something "unknown", the compiler generally assumes that global variables could be affected -- it doesn't really care whether you're calling a standardized library function that would allow him to assume that globals aren't changed.
If you declare the test as volatile, the output changes yet again:
stieber@gatekeeper:~ $ g++ -O3 Test.cpp; ./a.out
thread: 0
main: changed
loops: 481792699
thread: 1
1

Note how the output gets mangled because I'm not syncing the std::cout; however, you can still spot the changed output now.
In case you haven't encountered it before, volatile is an ancient keyword that predates modern civilization; it was used to indicate that something could just "change by itself". While it was meant to access things like hardware registers, I was just abusing it here to force the compiler to actually keep looking at the quit variable.
